# VUEX Getter. How do I grab the state from store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So, currently I have a list of projects created and stored in a module, imported through store and used in my "home" page.
I am using "mapGetters(['allProjects']), which is pulling in my list. But how do i reference that list in methods, etc.

My "projectList.js module" looks like so;

```
// Get db projects
import db from '@/firebase/init.js'

const state = {
  projectList: null

}

const getters = {
  allProjects: state => state.projectList
}

const actions = {
  fetchProjects ({ commit }) {
    if (state.projectList == null) {
      const projectLoop = []
      db.collection('Projects')
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const project = doc.data()
            project.id = doc.id
            projectLoop.push(project)
            // console.log(project)
          })
        })
      // console.log(projectList)
      commit('setProjects', projectLoop)
    }
  }
}

const mutations = {
  setProjects: (state, projects) => (state.projectList = projects)
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

Which I am then running from my homepage;

```
created() {this.fetchProjects()}
```

and the getting the results via

```
computed: mapGetters(['allProjects'])
```

I am able to use this in my code by using "project.title" but when i run something like

```
console.log('console-test ' + this.$store.getters.allProjects)
```

I get "console-test [object Object],[object Object]" how do i correctly call the array/object?

Answer (score 1):

In the component right way to use map getters is:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      allProjects: 'allProjects'
    })
  },
```

And Then you can call it

> console.log('console-test: ', this.allProjects)

Comment: Perfect, that console line works.
Can you explain the difference between the way i used mapGetters and the way you supplied? I followed a tutorial for VUEX so it may be outdated/not best practice but would like to know why?

Also, my projectList is a module i import into store/index. Would the path remain the same as you gave? (do i not need to import it into store/index.js?)

Comment: @KJParker it's all documented, read from https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper to the end of that page. It  covers both your use as well as the spread `...` operator use.

Comment: @KJParker your way(in the console) didnt add reactivity, but your mapGetter good, anyway i prefer to map specialised name to use it in component, cause when you have many getters standart name could make a trouble with code quality,
And i recommend u to avoid using mapGetter, use mapState and create filters for your need https://codeburst.io/vuex-getters-are-great-but-dont-overuse-them-9c946689b414